# Updating public/assets vs. resources/assets folder in Laravel, managing assets with Bower / Gulp

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, bower

I am just starting to learn Laravel and have some questions about the directory structure, updating with composer, gulp, bower, the "public" folder, "resources", etc.  Sorry, I am a newbie.

I got a Laravel Admin template online, so the setup there may be different than the raw install, but it seems basically the same:

```
app
bootstrap
config
database
public
resources
storage
tests
vendor
```

My question regards the assets folder under public and the assets folder under resources.  The template that I have uses gulp and bower, so my question is if I change some css or javascript for one of my files, should I do that in the /resources/assets path or the /public/assets path ?  Seems like you should update the resources and then do update with bower and gulp, otherwise your changes could get overwritten.  Does that apply to everything in the /resources/assets path ?  Update there and then update your /public/assets path ?

It does seem a little strange that the resources folder is essentially your development assets that can be compiled, but the views are in the resources folder, not the public folder.  Is that because they are xxx.blade files.php files, development files and are sort of compiled into xxx.php virtual files in the public directory at runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

You use Gulp and Bower to compile your custom assets in a more efficient way. If the template you downloaded makes use of these tools then you need to make your changes in the source files you feed Gulp/Bower and they take care of the rest and place the results in /resources/assets.

The /public/assets folder is where you or the template you downloaded save assets won't be edited by Gulp/Bower and can be accessible from the root path of your project. What ever you edit here will be kept like that until you make any manual modification again.